# Intermittent `A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource` when creating bucket

Tags: aws-sdk-go

We've seen the `conflicting conditional operation` intermittently in our CI pipeline when creating a new bucket. We create the bucket with a random name so there should be no conflicting operations. We're using the [terraform-aws-provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws), which uses the aws-sdk-go, to create this bucket. Looks like they call `CreateBucket` followed by `TagResource`. We *suspect* that this error is due to the provider not calling `WaitUntilBucketExists` before calling `TagResource`. Does this seems plausible? If so, we can open an issue or PR with the terraform aws provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the terraform code you're right, they do seem not to use `WaitUntilBucketExists`, you could check it here https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/27e2f31ac052cf5dce63036756337be08f2ffa30/aws/resource_aws_s3_bucket.go#L442

```
err := resource.Retry(5*time.Minute, func() *resource.RetryError {
    log.Printf("[DEBUG] Trying to create new S3 bucket: %q", bucket)
    _, err := s3conn.CreateBucket(req)
    if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
        if awsErr.Code() == "OperationAborted" {
            log.Printf("[WARN] Got an error while trying to create S3 bucket %s: %s", bucket, err)
            return resource.RetryableError(
                fmt.Errorf("[WARN] Error creating S3 bucket %s, retrying: %s",
                    bucket, err))
```

So basically they retry for 5 min... I guess you can open a Github issue or even better, create a PR :)

BTW, it's weird you hit the 5 minutes limit creating the bucket ... so I wonder if your CI could be hitting the threshold in AWS API rate limit. Could this be the case? Do you create several buckets at a time?

Comment: Based on the Terraform output, I think the bucket was successfully created but the subsequent tagging operation failed. The retry block for tags does not appear to retry on OperationAborted: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/27e2f31ac052cf5dce63036756337be08f2ffa30/aws/tags.go#L168-L171. I'll open an issue or PR next week.